# What causes the 006-0612 error and how can I prevent it?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I've played Monster Hunter 4 Ultimate online for many months without a problem. After taking a break from it I decided to play again recently, but I've been unable to play online at all.

I can connect to the servers just fine, but whenever I try to join another player's room, I'm met with error 006-0612 and I'm booted back offline. When setting up a room, people who join have the same problem. Discussions on the internet seem to offer various solutions such as dynamically/statically get an IP address or DNS, but nothing has worked for me. Why does this happen and how do I make it not happen?

Comment: [One Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MonsterHunter/comments/49dccm/3ds_error_0060612_solved/) says that they updated the firmware on their router and it fixed it for them

Comment: it's not neccesarily confined to the user's router. In researching it, the issue doesn't appear consistently for router brands, types, speeds, models, etc. I'ts something in the 3DS that I'd guess Nintendo can't recreate to address properly, or because of the Switch, aren't overly concerned about. I can track this issue back to 2011 on countless forums and a plethora of titles.